# Nodejs, phantomjs, heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, phantomjs

I used following buildpack to build a phantomjs / nodejs application on herouku, with no success:

http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git

and
http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs

```
phantom stderr: execvp(): Permission denied
/app/web.js:127
          return ph.createPage(function(err, page) {
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'createPage' of undefined
     at phantom.create.phantomPath (/app/web.js:127:18)
```

my webjs is:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // If there is _escaped_fragment_ option, it means we have to
  // generate the static HTML that should normally return the Javascript

  if(typeof(req.query._escaped_fragment_) !== "undefined") {
    phantom.create(function(err, ph) {
      return ph.createPage(function(err, page) {
        // We open phantomJS at the proper page.
        return page.open("http://myurl.com/#!" + req.query._escaped_fragment_, function(status) {
          return page.evaluate((function() {
            // We grab the content inside <html> tag...
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
          }), function(err, result) {
            // ... and we send it to the client.
            res.send(result);
            return ph.exit();
          });
        });
      });
    },{phantomPath:"/app/vendor/phantomjs/bin"});
  }
  else
    // If there is no _escaped_fragment_, we return the normal index template.
    //res.render('index');
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
```

if I run it locally on a macbook it works, I use node-phantom-simple without socket.io and cluster support.
I can't change the permissions on the phantomjs binary, they stay always 700, and heroku support told me, that i'm responsible for the permissions on the files via buildpack.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Patrick

Comment: Any luck with this Patrick?? I'm also stumbling with the same issue.

Comment: no, I had no luck. I used https://prerender.io/ for a crawlable site...